# CakePHP $this->Auth->user("id") always return null?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a function that I use to get the user id of Auth component. It works fine without use `return json_encode`. The problem is that I need this works with json_encode because I get values from ajax request. 
Using `json_encode` it always return `null` to id and I can't understand why does it occur. The problem is with the function `indexAjax()` below.

How could I use `$this->Auth->user("id")` with `json_encode` and it not return null ?

Trying.

```
//using $this->set it works fine
public function index() {       
                $id = $this->Auth->user("id");                
                $empresas = $this->Empresa->find('all', array(
                            'fields'=>array("id", "nomeFantasia", "cnpj",
                                    "telefone1", "telefone2", "celular", "aberto"),
                            'conditions'=>array("users_id = "=> $id)            
                           ));             
                debug($id) or die;
                //$this->set(compact('empresas'));
    }



//with json_encode always return null
 public function indexAjax() {      
                $this->autoRender = false;
                $id = $this->Auth->user("id");
                $empresas = $this->Empresa->find('all', array(
                            'fields'=>array("id", "nomeFantasia", "cnpj",
                                    "telefone1", "telefone2", "celular", "aberto"),
                            'conditions'=>array("users_id = "=> $id)            
                           ));
                return json_encode($id);                
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

solved the problem. My solution was when user make login I get the  user id and write in session so when I need this id I get from session directly and not from AuthComponent.

It works.